# Polarization of 3 MOSFET

Tags: mosfet

How can I calculate the polarization parameters for each MOSFET transistor?
There is an internal resistance in the input signal of 100k. RS1 = RS2 = 423 \$\Omega\$ and Vdd = 17 V.

[image]

I got two values for \$V_S\$ for the first transistor and I wanted to know which one would have to choose for the transistor to be in the saturation region. The \$V_S\$ values I obtained were -0.283 V and -3.193 V. (please check if it is correct). I used:

\$V_{GS}>V_T\$

\$V_{DS}>V_{GS}-V_T\$

\$V_T=-0,95\$

\$\frac{\mu_0 C_{OX}W}{L}=1,5\,mA/V^2\$

---

My calculations:

[image]

First transistor:
\$I_{RD1}=I_{RD2}\$

\$\frac{V_{DD}-V_D}{R_{D1}}=\frac{V_S}{R_{S1}}\$

\$I_D\approx I_{D\,SAT}=\frac{\mu_0 C_{OX} W}{2L}(V_{GS}-V_T)^2\$

\$I_{D\,SAT}=1,5\times 10^{-3}\times (-V_S+0,95)^2\$

\$\frac{V_S}{R_{S1}}=1,5\times 10^{-3}\times (-V_S+0,95)^2\$

\$0,6345V_S^2-2,20555V_S+0,5726=0\$

\$V_S=0,283\,V\$ or \$V_S=3,193\,V\$

So:

For \$V_S=0,283\,V\$:

\$V_D=15,93\,V\$

\$V_{DS}=1,73\,V\$

For \$V_S=3,193\,V\$:

\$V_D=4,92\,V\$

\$V_{DS}=1,73\,V\$

Check that the transistor is in the saturation zone to know what value for \$V_S\$ to choose:

For \$V_S=0,283\,V\$:

\$V_{GS}>V_T\$

\$-0,283>-0,95\$ check!

\$V_{DS}>V_{GS}-V_T\$

\$15,65>0,665\$ check!

For \$V_S=3,193\,V\$:

\$V_{GS}>V_T\$

\$-3,193>-0,95\$ false!

\$V_{DS}>V_{GS}-V_T\$

\$1,727>-2,243\$ check!

I do not know where the error will be. It should be false under both conditions.

Comment: Well, first thing I notice is that those are JFETs, not MOSFETs.

Comment: @Felthry Thanks. So the equation for \$I_D\$ is wrong right? Do I have to use the equation that encompasses \$I_{DSS}\$?

Comment: @Felthry Why is the title that my teacher put into the problem is: Amplifier with 3 transistors with MOSFET? Where is the MOSFET in the circuit? And what is a MOSFET?

Comment: I'm not sure where you're going wrong in this--I haven't looked over it in any detail. There is no MOSFET in the circuit at all; I don't know why your teacher called it that but the only transistors here are JFETs. MOSFETs and JFETs are similar types of transistor in that they are both FETs, but they behave quite differently in some modes of operation.

Comment: Maybe they don't have a depletion MOSFET schematic symbol. Also, why didn't you divide \$\frac{\mu_0 C_{OX}W}{L}=K_P = 1.5\,mA/V^2 \$ by two?